# How to avoid "tex capacity exceeded" with several tikzset definitions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, capacity

### Problem

I'm defining several `.pic` keys using `tikzset` to be consumed later on other libraries. However, when I'm using `pdflatex`, for example, I get a capacity exceeded error.

I just tested that using `lualatex` seems to be fine for the moment. However, I didn't want to restrict to just one program to compile the documents.

I was thinking if there is a way to define the keys dynamically, or not to process them all when reading the document, but loading them on demand. Or since the `.pic` definitions will be in the same document it will be impossible to avoid the error.

Any thoughts and suggestions are welcomed.

### MWE

To get an idea of what I'm talking about, check the code below.

What I'm doing is to create several keys with `svg` on the `.pic`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\tikzset{
  cog/.pic = {
    \fill[scale=0.004em] svg {M863.24,382.771l-88.759-14.807c-6.451-26.374-15.857-51.585-28.107-75.099l56.821-70.452c12.085-14.889,11.536-36.312-1.205-50.682l-35.301-39.729c-12.796-14.355-34.016-17.391-50.202-7.165l-75.906,47.716c-33.386-23.326-71.204-40.551-112-50.546l-14.85-89.235c-3.116-18.895-19.467-32.759-38.661-32.759h-53.198c-19.155,0-35.561,13.864-38.608,32.759l-14.931,89.263c-33.729,8.258-65.353,21.588-94.213,39.144l-72.188-51.518c-15.558-11.115-36.927-9.377-50.504,4.171l-37.583,37.61c-13.548,13.577-15.286,34.946-4.142,50.504l51.638,72.326c-17.391,28.642-30.584,60.086-38.841,93.515l-89.743,14.985C13.891,385.888,0,402.24,0,421.435v53.156c0,19.193,13.891,35.547,32.757,38.663l89.743,14.985c6.781,27.508,16.625,53.784,29.709,78.147L95.647,676.44c-12.044,14.875-11.538,36.312,1.203,50.669l35.274,39.73c12.797,14.382,34.028,17.363,50.216,7.163l77-48.37c32.581,22.285,69.44,38.664,108.993,48.37l14.931,89.25c3.048,18.896,19.453,32.76,38.608,32.76h53.198c19.194,0,35.545-13.863,38.661-32.759l14.875-89.25c33.308-8.147,64.531-21.245,93.134-38.5l75.196,53.705c15.53,11.155,36.915,9.405,50.478-4.186l37.598-37.597c13.532-13.536,15.365-34.893,4.127-50.479l-53.536-75.059c17.441-28.738,30.704-60.238,38.909-93.816l88.758-14.82c18.921-3.116,32.756-19.469,32.756-38.663v-53.156C895.998,402.24,882.163,385.888,863.24,382.771zM449.42,616.013c-92.764,0-168-75.25-168-168c0-92.764,75.236-168,168-168c92.748,0,167.998,75.236,167.998,168C617.418,540.763,542.168,616.013,449.42,616.013z};
  },
  monitor/.pic = {
    \fill[scale=0.01em] svg {M145.407,248.988l-2.775,26.209c-0.224,2.115,0.46,4.225,1.883,5.806c1.422,1.581,3.449,2.483,5.576,2.483h79.301c2.126,0,4.153-0.903,5.576-2.483c1.422-1.581,2.106-3.691,1.883-5.806l-2.775-26.209h98.777c15.374,0,27.881-12.507,27.881-27.881V27.881C360.733,12.507,348.225,0,332.852,0H40.63C25.256,0,12.749,12.507,12.749,27.881v193.226c0,15.374,12.507,27.881,27.881,27.881H145.407z M221.055,268.487h-62.629l2.064-19.499h58.5L221.055,268.487z M40.63,15h292.222c7.103,0,12.881,5.778,12.881,12.881V197.99H27.749V27.881C27.749,20.778,33.527,15,40.63,15z M27.749,221.107v-8.117h317.983v8.117c0,7.103-5.778,12.881-12.881,12.881H40.63C33.527,233.988,27.749,228.21,27.749,221.107z};
  },
  notepad/.pic = {
   \fill svg {M29.334,3H25V1c0-0.553-0.447-1-1-1s-1,0.447-1,1v2h-6V1c0-0.553-0.448-1-1-1s-1,0.447-1,1v2H9V1c0-0.553-0.448-1-1-1S7,0.447,7,1v2H2.667C1.194,3,0,4.193,0,5.666v23.667C0,30.806,1.194,32,2.667,32h26.667C30.807,32,32,30.806,32,29.333V5.666C32,4.193,30.807,3,29.334,3z M30,29.333C30,29.701,29.701,30,29.334,30H2.667C2.299,30,2,29.701,2,29.333V5.666C2,5.299,2.299,5,2.667,5H7v2c0,0.553,0.448,1,1,1s1-0.447,1-1V5h6v2c0,0.553,0.448,1,1,1s1-0.447,1-1V5h6v2c0,0.553,0.447,1,1,1s1-0.447,1-1V5h4.334C29.701,5,30,5.299,30,5.666V29.333z};  
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {cog}; 

  \pic at (2,0) {monitor};

  \pic at (4,0) {notepad};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Current problems

- The library can be added if I use `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`, regardless of the number of `\pic` in use. My assumption is that the memory runs out when it is trying to load all the definitions into memory.

  Hence, I was wondering to get a dynamic way of loading or defining the pics.
- There is no malformation of the keys, since it compiles with `lualatex`.

Comment: It would be hard to exhaust the symbols as such unless you recursively define them. Can you give an example or cut down the number of `pic`s and check if the problem goes away?

Comment: MWE? Maybe you only forgot a comma...

Comment: @percusse if I cut some of the shapes from the file it will load without the problem. 

So, I was thinking if there is a way to load them dynamically. Kind of using a `.code` to create the key definition when called. But, since the `svg` must be somewhere, I'm not sure if that will give the same problem.

Comment: Which capacity is exceeded?

Comment: @cfr is TeX capacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After been thinking about the problem, I thought that if the problem is the huge file, I can divide it into several files.

My approach is to not define any key, and when the `pic` is going to be used, then I will load the particular file.

My solution is

```
\tikzset{
  /tikz/pics/.unknown/.code={%
    \let\currentname\pgfkeyscurrentname%
    \input{\currentname.tex}%
    \pgfkeysalso{\currentname/.try}%
  }
}
```

Simply, check if the `pic` is unknown and load the file. I was doing some conditional loading with `\IfFileExists`, but when it didn't I got strange errors where `tikz` was trying to parse the failure. And decided against it.

There seems to be a problem with the definition of the keys, since when you use the `pic` several times it loads the file again. It seems like the definition of the key is not persisting (not sure why).

(Any better or more clever solutions are still welcomed

### Full Example

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{cog.tex}
\tikzset{
  cog/.pic = {
    \fill[scale=0.004em] svg {M863.24,382.771l-88.759-14.807c-6.451-26.374-15.857-51.585-28.107-75.099l56.821-70.452c12.085-14.889,11.536-36.312-1.205-50.682l-35.301-39.729c-12.796-14.355-34.016-17.391-50.202-7.165l-75.906,47.716c-33.386-23.326-71.204-40.551-112-50.546l-14.85-89.235c-3.116-18.895-19.467-32.759-38.661-32.759h-53.198c-19.155,0-35.561,13.864-38.608,32.759l-14.931,89.263c-33.729,8.258-65.353,21.588-94.213,39.144l-72.188-51.518c-15.558-11.115-36.927-9.377-50.504,4.171l-37.583,37.61c-13.548,13.577-15.286,34.946-4.142,50.504l51.638,72.326c-17.391,28.642-30.584,60.086-38.841,93.515l-89.743,14.985C13.891,385.888,0,402.24,0,421.435v53.156c0,19.193,13.891,35.547,32.757,38.663l89.743,14.985c6.781,27.508,16.625,53.784,29.709,78.147L95.647,676.44c-12.044,14.875-11.538,36.312,1.203,50.669l35.274,39.73c12.797,14.382,34.028,17.363,50.216,7.163l77-48.37c32.581,22.285,69.44,38.664,108.993,48.37l14.931,89.25c3.048,18.896,19.453,32.76,38.608,32.76h53.198c19.194,0,35.545-13.863,38.661-32.759l14.875-89.25c33.308-8.147,64.531-21.245,93.134-38.5l75.196,53.705c15.53,11.155,36.915,9.405,50.478-4.186l37.598-37.597c13.532-13.536,15.365-34.893,4.127-50.479l-53.536-75.059c17.441-28.738,30.704-60.238,38.909-93.816l88.758-14.82c18.921-3.116,32.756-19.469,32.756-38.663v-53.156C895.998,402.24,882.163,385.888,863.24,382.771zM449.42,616.013c-92.764,0-168-75.25-168-168c0-92.764,75.236-168,168-168c92.748,0,167.998,75.236,167.998,168C617.418,540.763,542.168,616.013,449.42,616.013z};
  }
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{monitor.tex}
\tikzset{
  monitor/.pic = {
    \fill[scale=0.01em] svg {M145.407,248.988l-2.775,26.209c-0.224,2.115,0.46,4.225,1.883,5.806c1.422,1.581,3.449,2.483,5.576,2.483h79.301c2.126,0,4.153-0.903,5.576-2.483c1.422-1.581,2.106-3.691,1.883-5.806l-2.775-26.209h98.777c15.374,0,27.881-12.507,27.881-27.881V27.881C360.733,12.507,348.225,0,332.852,0H40.63C25.256,0,12.749,12.507,12.749,27.881v193.226c0,15.374,12.507,27.881,27.881,27.881H145.407z M221.055,268.487h-62.629l2.064-19.499h58.5L221.055,268.487z M40.63,15h292.222c7.103,0,12.881,5.778,12.881,12.881V197.99H27.749V27.881C27.749,20.778,33.527,15,40.63,15z M27.749,221.107v-8.117h317.983v8.117c0,7.103-5.778,12.881-12.881,12.881H40.63C33.527,233.988,27.749,228.21,27.749,221.107z};
  }
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{notepad.tex}
\tikzset{
  notepad/.pic = {
    \fill svg {M29.334,3H25V1c0-0.553-0.447-1-1-1s-1,0.447-1,1v2h-6V1c0-0.553-0.448-1-1-1s-1,0.447-1,1v2H9V1c0-0.553-0.448-1-1-1S7,0.447,7,1v2H2.667C1.194,3,0,4.193,0,5.666v23.667C0,30.806,1.194,32,2.667,32h26.667C30.807,32,32,30.806,32,29.333V5.666C32,4.193,30.807,3,29.334,3z M30,29.333C30,29.701,29.701,30,29.334,30H2.667C2.299,30,2,29.701,2,29.333V5.666C2,5.299,2.299,5,2.667,5H7v2c0,0.553,0.448,1,1,1s1-0.447,1-1V5h6v2c0,0.553,0.448,1,1,1s1-0.447,1-1V5h6v2c0,0.553,0.447,1,1,1s1-0.447,1-1V5h4.334C29.701,5,30,5.299,30,5.666V29.333z};  
  }
}
\end{filecontents}

\tikzset{
  /tikz/pics/.unknown/.code={%
    \let\currentname\pgfkeyscurrentname%
    \input{\currentname.tex}%
    \pgfkeysalso{\currentname/.try}%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {cog}; 

  \pic at (2,0) {monitor};

  \pic at (4,0) {notepad};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How many pics are we talking about here roughly? Thousands?

Comment: @percusse yes in the thousands.

Comment: How do you define them? Recursively? There is no way you hand crafted all of them which is why I'm suspicious about the code.

Comment: Yea with a script in Python. So, defining them over several files was not a problem. The issue is that I end up with thousands of files, instead of a single library file. Hence, my question.

Comment: I can imagine because I think you are not defining a parametric pic but actually defining one pic per parameter which is causing this.